# Automatically set audio input level

Tags: windows, audio

I work for a company that provides a software solution with a dictation component that is often used over RDP - sometimes thin clients.  The software is on the server, but the mic is plugged in locally.  We provide dictation microphones (either a Philips SpeechMike or an Olympus RecMic).  The issue is that the input volume is set high, and it's usually a loud environment, so we're looking for a good way to set the input volume automatically.  From all the reading I've done, it seems this isn't a thing, but I figured I'd ask the experts here before giving up. I've spoken to Olympus engineering, and it's not an option they're aware of, and I'm waiting on Philips' reply.  But I was hoping there might be something outside of their keys/tools etc. How does Windows keep track of this setting? There has to be some way to do it.

I know there are a couple of possible options.  Setting the Remote Audio level on the server seems like it would be the easiest, as it would be microphone device/manufacturer agnostic, but since that 'input device' doesn't have a levels tab, or volume slider, I'm thinking that's not an option.

The other, current method is to set the microphone level on the local (Windows based) machine, be it thin client or thick.  It's a manual process at this point, but I'm hoping there is some way to set it, probably in the registry?

TIA for any guidance

Comment: My guess would be the registry. One way may be to run ProcMon, change the volume, stop ProcMon, then examine where any settings may be saved (registry or file). (This doesn't always work, some settings need to be loaded by an control UI).

Comment: Thanks Greg. I totally forgot about procmon, great idea.  It helped narrow it down to a key:


`HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceClasses\{6994ad04-93ef-11d0-a3cc-00a0c9223196}\##?#USB#VID_07B4&PID_0296&MI_01#7&1935cd3a&0&0001#{6994ad04-93ef-11d0-a3cc-00a0c9223196}\#GLOBAL\Properties\{7fb7b48f-531d-44a2-bcb3-5ad5a134b3dc}\20001\(Default) `


Unfortunately I can't get into the Properties section, but this definitely helps.